# How to move space from my XFS /home partition to XFS root partition

Tags: linux, centos7, lvm, partition, xfs

I am running centos 7 minimal. My /home partition is about 500gb and root is only 50gb. I need help figuring out how to reduce the /home partition so I have free space to allocate to the root partition.

My /home and root partitions are XFS file systems. I have not been able to find steps of how to get root to have more space by reducing other partitions because I know I cannot shrink an XFS file systems. So I am confused about how I can accomplish this since this is xfs.

```
[root@openstackcontroller ~]# df -h
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/cl-root   50G   15G   36G  29% /
devtmpfs              63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 63G     0   63G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 63G  9.0M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                 63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1           1014M  233M  782M  23% /boot
tmpfs                 13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
/dev/mapper/cl-home  503G  4.2G  499G   1% /home
[root@openstackcontroller ~]#
```

For the end result, I'd like to have the /home be 20gb so I can give all the rest to root.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, 50GB for `/` is plenty in most cases.

If you need to shrink XFS anyway, the only way is to recreate the FS and restore from backup.

The steps would be:

- Do a backup.
- Unmount the `/home` FS
- Resize the partitions and grow the one for `/` (or use `lvresize` in case you use LVM, which appears to be the case).
- xfs_grow `/`.
- `mkfs` a new `/home` FS and mount it.
- Restore from backup.

As it appears that your current `/home` is nearly empty, this should be a very quick process that doesn't even need a reboot.

Another option: Move stuff to `/home` and link it back. Things like database data directories,  `/var/log` and `/opt` are good candidates.

Comment: Thanks! Would I use xfsdump and xfsrestore to backup and restore the /home FS?

Comment: You can, but in most cases, plain `cp` or `rsync` would be sufficient.

Comment: I thought I could not do lvresize on fxs FS's?

Comment: After you reduced the size of `/home` with `lvresize`, you need to recreate the filesystem with `mkfs`. All that `lvresize` does is to alter the size of the block device where the file system is living, but not the filesystem itself.

Comment: I just double checking since I'm very new to linux file systems I would run the following commands:

1. cp /home PATH_TO_BACKUP
2. umount /home 
3. lvresize -L 20G /dev/mapper/cl-home
4. xfs_grow /
5. mkfs.xfs -f /home
6. rsync PATH_TO_BACKUP

Comment: Not sure if I have the syntax for these command correct

Comment: Regarding `50GB for / is plenty in most cases.` - but where should I store the data then? I.e. I host a website and obviously I don't want to put the files in `/home`. Usually I'd put it somewhere near `/var/www/mywebsite`, but this is obviously located in `/`